# Home button override in android. Issue in start up when reboot the phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a application when I click the Home Button. To do that I used in AndroidManifest.xml the next lines:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

So the first time I click in home button the system ask me: to go to home page or to go to my application, and then to choose one time or always.
I choose always because always I click in Home Button I want to start my application, then i click back and i go back to home screen.

But there is a problem. When I reboot the phone. Turn off then turn on, the first thing the system make is launch my application and not go to home screen. I want to avoid that off course. At this time I can only avoid if I choose to start my application one time but that is not what i want.

There is some code to add to block the application to run when I turn on the phone?

If i choose always my app I block in my app in start-up phone and need to go to definitions to erase the app to make possible to go to homescreen.

I have tried to install "StartUp Manager" app to erase my app from start up but my app dont apper in user tab. There are some options in System tab but i dont know what to choose or even if it works.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you please rewise your question a bit? So you want to open your application, every time you click the home button? If you don't want your application to be a launcher, there is no 'supported' way to detect a home button click, outside of your application. There are some ways to accomplish this, rather inside than outside of the app, but they are all not supported and will end up working only somehow on only a few devices.

Comment: Yes, every time i click the home button I want to open my app. The only thing I dont want is that my application automatic start when I turn on the phone. I only want when the homescreen apears and then I click in the home button to my app starts. I don't know if i am beeing obvious. Thank You.

Comment: Then your way as you descriped it in the post above is the way to go. At least, it is the most stable one. Unfortunately (but good for security) the user has to accept your app as launcher. Once done, your app will start if the home button get's clicked. Consider to check the Intent which starts your application or the time since the device is started to differentiate home tap from first device start.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't

The launcher application is exactly that, literally - first to launch when the phone boots and the one to launch when a user presses the HOME button no matter where or during the runtime of what application.

@strider 's code will give you an event to intercept and do something when the device finishes boot but it will not replace the launcher with the default launcher.

The only way i know of to badly mimic what you're asking is to use that event and launch the default launcher application but that is an ugly hack which will require the user to authorize the default launcher every time.

Every other option requires you to sign you launcher application with the system KeyStore in order to gain system permissions which would allow you to additional permissions but even that will not provide you with all that you're asking for.

Sorry.

Comment: Actually there are ways to accomplish this without beeing Launcher, but they are all "hacky" and do not work with every device. Since that, it's more : The answer is that you should't!

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was bad, srry, I think I misunderstood your question.

Maybe this is a better idea:
Use a broadcast receiver to see if device has just booted

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
</intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

and the `MyBroadcastReceiver.java` :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Device just booted (close your app or something) so it will show homescreen
    }
}
```

Comment: I remove the lines from AndroidManifest.xml and then add this code but when I click in home button my application don't open.

Comment: Ah...  my bad, thought he would go from one Activity to an other one

Comment: Changed it now, maybe this will help you out ;)

Comment: If you add good code for detecting the home button outside of the app, too,I will give you my vote. The interesting part here is, will the receiver called before his/her activity is started or afterwards? If it will be called before, than how would you suggest to be sure, if it is the start intent from the current boot or the home button clicked by the user?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re you are right, the app is already started before the receiver is called. I don't know if it is possible to dynamically add the `intent.category.HOME` ifso, you could maybe add the intent when the boot receiver is called, en use `getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());` to clear the settings on a `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` receiver.